# Linux append to single line in file

Tags: linux, awk, append, line

I have run the below command which outputs the current IP address of eth0 and sends the output to a textfile named ip.txt

```
ifconfig | grep -A 1 'eth0' | tail -1 | cut -d ':' -f 2 | cut -d ' ' -f 1 > ip.txt
```

I have a second config file. I want to append the text in the newly created file ip.txt onto the end of line 2 of this file. File 2 has the following data:

```
[root@******]# cat File2.txt
Device=
IPADDR=
NETWORK=
NETMASK=
.......
```

I need it to look like this

```
[root@******]# cat File2.txt
Device=
IPADDR=someip
NETWORK=
NETMASK=
.......
```

This is probably possible using AWK or sed but I can't seem to get it to work correctly. Can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sed -i "s/IPADDR=/IPADDR=`cat ip.txt`/g" File2.txt
```

Comment: @senator404, I don't understand. This modifies the content of File2.txt as mentioned in the question. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You could try the below awk command,

```
$ awk -v var=$(awk '{print $0}' ip.txt) '/IPADDR=/{$2=var; print$1$2}!/IPADDR=/{print}' File2.txt
Device=
IPADDR=someip
NETWORK=
NETMASK=
```

Comment: Hi, This prints the correct information to screen but what I need is it to copy the information to a file. Thanks

Comment: you mean just copy it into another file. Then use `awk -v var=$(awk '{print $0}' ip.txt) '/IPADDR=/{$2=var; print$1$2}!/IPADDR=/{print}' File2.txt > File3.txt`

Comment: it will creates a new file file3.txt and appends the text which was printed on the console to that file.